# jQuery.tablesorter with Lazy Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, tablesorter

I'm attempting to run tablesorter and lazy load together, but when I sort the table the images stop loading. I can't seem to figure this one out on the approach.
Any help would be appreciated.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#table").tablesorter();
    }
);
$(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
      effect : "fadeIn"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting table will generate new position for images, so you could execute lazy load after sorting end.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#table").tablesorter();
     $("#table").bind("sortEnd",function(e, table) {
         $("img.lazy").lazyload({
            effect : "fadeIn"
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't figure out the `bind("sort"end"` trigger. This worked perfectly!